# Temporary supporting rafters in the middle for beam installation

Tags: structural

I am intending to remove a load bearing wall that lies between the old perimeter of the house and the new extension. 
It is holding the extremities of the old roof rafters as well as a wall holding part of the extension. 
I would need to install a beam instead of the load bearing wall I want to remove. 
I'm not worried much about supporting the extension but
I'm struggling to figure out how to temporarily hold the rafters before removing the wall and installing the beam. I would have to hold the rafters somewhere before their extremities. 
So how do I attach a temporary supporting wall to the rafters and without damaging the rafters. 
I highly appreciate your support. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question, and big props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; most newcomers don't bother...

Comment: I was looking at simpson and hurricane ties. Any better ideas or warnings?

Comment: Is the roof flat, or do we have to worry about a peak collapsing? Not in the middle; build a temp wall about one foot into the kitchen with top and bottom runners, and cross bracing to prevent racking. Screw the top runner to each joist, and put a 2-by-X stud underneath each joist. - Given what we're looking at, 2x4's should be fine, considering it's a single top plate and one of the doorway headers is the wrong way, and the one that isn't is missing its king studs....

Comment: Hi Mazura, thank you for your answer, sorry I wasn't notified. Both old and extension roofs are not flat. The extension is actually steeper, and this wall is carrying its peak. Your explanation of the joist support is very clear, but I'm not sure how to support the rafters without touching their extremities. Also do you think it's a good idea to use a steel beam? I'm thinking of U shape. http://tiny.cc/o9oxcz